# Proof of IVT by long exact sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

I am trying to prove the intermediate value theorem stated as:

Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function with $f(a)=c$ and $f(b)=d$, then $[c,d] \subseteq \operatorname{im}(f)$.

By contradiction via long exact sequence of a pair. So clearly I need to show that if we assume that there exists a point $p\in[c,d]$ that is not in $\operatorname{im}(f)$ we get a contradiction. I think this is a relative homology problem. I'm not sure if I am doing this correctly at all but, we can take the set $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}= \space (-\infty,p)\space \cup \space (p,\infty)$ and we have that $\mathbb{R} \space / \space U$ treats anything not equal to $p$ as the same thing. So now we have the spaces $U$, $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbb{R} \space / \space U$.  Is this even the right idea so far? And 
I'm not too sure exactly how to go about creating a long exact sequence from these spaces.

I guess it may just be 
$$H_0(U)\to H_0(\mathbb{R})\to H_0(\mathbb{R} \space / \space U)\to 0$$

and so 
$$\operatorname{dim}(\mathbb{R})=\operatorname{dim}(U)+\operatorname{dim}(\mathbb{R} \space / \space U)$$
and we get that $\operatorname{dim}(\mathbb{R} \space / \space U)=-1$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: I'm curious:  where did this exercise come from?

Comment: @XanderHenderson I am in an applied topology seminar course at my school and it is a problem on the most recent problem set written by my professor

Comment: It would be quite surprising if you were assigned to do this problem if you were not told at some point what the long exact sequence for homology is… That makes your last sentence quite weird.

Comment: I'm curious what the background is, what you can assume. If you know that $[a,b]$ is connected, then it seems easier to look at the disjoint open sets $[a,b] = f^{-1}(-\infty, p) \cup f^{-1}(p,\infty)$ to see that there can be no such $p$. If you are using that $H_0$ gives the number of path components, then you need to know something about path connectedness?